# How to add dynamic checkboxes in a Blazor-server app that use a list of booleans?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

To clarify my question more I'll first show you add a checkbox using the blazor component library I'm using:

```
<MudCheckBox @bind-Checked="@Basic_CheckBox1"></MudCheckBox>
@code{
public bool Basic_CheckBox1 { get; set; } = false;
}
```

the code above creates a checkbox and then toggles the boolean Basic_CheckBox1 to true or false based on if the checkbox is checked or not.
here is my code

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < checkboxNames.Count; i++)
        {

            <MudCheckBox @bind-Checked="@checkboxBools[i]" Label="@checkboxNames[i]"></MudCheckBox>
        }
```

this code works until I check or uncheck my created checkboxes, then I get the index out of range error, how can I fix this? I need to use a list of booleans because I don't know how many checkboxes I will need until runtime, if there is any other solution please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it like the bind isn't done there and then in the loop, but later. By the time the bind comes to be done, the value of `i` is off the end of the array Length, having been incremented repeatedly. Instead, you can save the current value of your loop variable `i` into another variable, then use that other variable in your bind:

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < checkboxNames.Length; i++)
    {
        var x = i;
        <MudCheckBox @bind-Checked="@checkboxBools[x]" Label="@checkboxNames[i]"></MudCheckBox>
    }
```

checkBoxBools should be an array/list that is the same length (initalized to have the same number of elements as) checkBoxNames.. For example:

```
    string[] checkboxNames = new string[]{"a","b","c"};
    bool[] checkboxBools = new bool[3];
```

Or, if something else is providing a variable number of names:

```
    checkboxNames = context.People.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
    checkboxBools = new bool[checkBoxNames.Length];
```

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GamQEFuFIwdRbzEx